# Kali 2.0 (Dojo) Upgrade Login issues

Tags: linux, login

Today I upgraded my Kali Linux OS to Dojo or 2.0.

There were several issues during installation, the most major being a crash. I'm not sure at what point of the installation it was at, but the screen went to sleep and went I went to move the mouse to wake it back up, there were several empty black squares where text should be. If you've ever booted a live Linux OS from a flash drive and had it disconnect during use you will know what I'm talking about.

After restarting I redid the `apt-get dist-upgrade` command and went through the installation normally. After a restart, I was brought to the grub and then to the boot like normal. After fully booting I was brought to a black screen. I assumed it was a driver issue, did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, then reinstalled several graphical drivers through the repos.

After a reboot it opened to a "Oh no! Something has gone wrong!" Window. Again I did a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> logged in tried a `startx`. It said the command did not exist. Next I installed *x-window-system* just so I could do `startx`. Success, I was now in the Kali-Dojo desktop. After a few personal configurations, rearranging the grub is the only thing I can recall at the moment, but I feel there was another change made, probably irrelevant.

Either way after the restart I was brought back to the "Oh no! Something has gone wrong!" window. I redid the previous, without needing to reinstall *x-window-system*.

Any ideas on how I can avoid the need to bring up the text interface and do startx on EVERY reboot? Is this a configuration issue? Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well it looks like I've found my own answer. After the initial installation and I was having the issue of the black screen, and before I had done the key combo for text mode, I had tried editing the grub so that it would boot to the login screen.

One of the changes I had made involved adding `radeon.modeset=0` (This will be different depending on your graphics card) to the line `linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=(Your UUID for your system here) ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet`.

Out of interest I decided to try this just as testing. After making this edit the system booted successfully into the login, despite a few fails while starting openvas, postgresql, and something having to do with screen brightness.